# Search a string array with substrings contained in the array Swift 4.x

Tags: swift, string, substring

```
["A2A1", "A1A2", "A1B1", "B1A1", "B1C1", "C1B1", "D3E3", "E4E3", "E3D3", "E3E4"]
```

I want to find all strings that start with duplicates  ("**A1**A2", "**A1**B1") ("**B1**A1", "**B1**C1")

The array changes.  It will not always be the same.

How can I search a String array with substrings contained within the array?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Will the strings always have this form?

Comment: Yes.  The form is the same.

Comment: So here's a first step towards a solution: why don't you write some simple code to parse `"A2A1"` into `("A2", "A1")`

Comment: Yeah... its a little more complicated that what I am showing.  I can do it in multiple steps.  That being one option.  Or filtering the the string and then checking the prefix.  But adding extra steps to this process increases problems all over the place.  It would be extremely helpful if I could get it done in one loop, and then proceed.  But thanks.

Comment: That's not how programming works. You should aim to decompose complex data into simpler data that's easier to work with, and breaking down complex problems into a composition of simpler problems. That way you have an easier time solving them, and your code becomes more reusable because although it may be unlikely that you run into the exact problems again, you're more likely to run into the same sub-problems again, so you could reuse that code. Whether it's one loop or not is rather irrelevant. This code should be in its own set of separate functions.

Comment: This is data produced after a 'flood fill' algortihm completes.  What it will allow me to do is to find all the squares.  So I can programmatically create puzzle games like KenKen, Go, Sudoko.   Its really tricky, and adding any steps to this multidimensional array process expounds the problem logarithmically.  So in this weird case, if I break down the problem into smaller problems it creates more problems to solve.  LOL.

Comment: Then you haven't sufficiently broken down your code into small isolated pieces. For one, your flood fill algorithm should return a `[GridCoordPair]`, not `[String]`, where `GridCoord` is a datatype that encapsulates 2 `GridCoords`. You're making your life a lot harder by outputting strings, for example, because then you're making yourself do work to split strings back apart (after you just glued them together!)

Comment: Thanks.  I am sure my code could be better!   The reason I glued them together? I was able to determine that Any pair with a duplicate in the front is an island of 3 or more.  And any without is exactly an island of two.  And then from that data I can determine all the squares.   Changing it to strings is merely so I don't go insane with multidimensional array numbers.  But yes, that is an extra unneeded step.  I could have had glued together gird coordinates instead of Strings. Best of luck.

Comment: "to determine that Any pair with a duplicate in the front is an island of 3 or more. And any without is exactly an island of two. " Yep, that's a good argument for why you need a datatype that lets you easily access the 2 components of your "coordinate". "Changing it to strings is merely so I don't go insane with multidimensional array numbers. " Using multidimensional arrays would be an inappropriate choice of data structure. But String is even worse. You'd be mucking about with string concatenation, only to then have to use `prefix(2)` and `suffix(2)` all over the place.

Comment: I would advise you to make something like a `GridCoords` struct, which stores the letter/number of each sqaure (making them easy to access!), as well as providing convenience methods (e.g. `getSquareAbove()`, `getSquareBelow()`, `getSquareToTheLeft()`, `getSquareToTheRight()`, etc.). You can then make a `GridCoordPair` struct that wraps 2 `GridCoords`. Your flood fill algorithm would then return a `[GridCoordPair]`.

Comment: Using these proper data types would make it *much* easier to work with this data. Rather than mucking with low level details of string processing/splitting/gluing, you can express natural things like `Dictionary(grouping: floodedPairs, by: { $0.firstSquare }`

Comment: Ok.  I will concede that is a better solution.  I did not want to 'tinker' with the algorithm at all, but OK having it spit out a variable in a self-defined struct is a lot more efficient.    It may require me running through the multi-loop twice though.  So I could have an absolute ridiculous three level loop through a two dimensional array, not exactly a fun thing to do.  LOL.   But OK I understand this, and agree.  Thanks!

Comment: Where do you get idea that you need a multi dimensional array from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you all elements with a duplicate prefix into an unidimensional array:

```
var elements = ["A2A1", "A1A2", "A1B1", "B1A1", "B1C1", "C1B1", "D3E3", "E4E3", "E3D3", "E3E4"]

let elementsWithDupPrefix = elements.filter { (str) -> Bool in
    let prefix = String(str.prefix(2))
    return elements.firstIndex(where: { $0.hasPrefix(prefix) }) != elements.lastIndex(where: { $0.hasPrefix(prefix) })
}
```

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you so much.  One problem down.  233,265 more to go!!  Works like a charm.

Comment: You're welcome! Then you may want to keep only unique values in case the original array has "A1B1" two times for example. You can easily do that by converting the array to a Set and then back to an Array. But I'm sure it's not the only way.

Comment: This would scale really badly with large arrays. It's doing two `O(n)` operations per predicate, which themselves run `O(n)` times, making this `O(n^2)`

Comment: Yes you're right, I didn't consider complexity here.

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
let strings = ["A2A1", "A1A2", "A1B1", "B1A1", "B1C1", "C1B1", "D3E3", "E4E3", "E3D3", "E3E4"]
```

You can do:

```
let duplicates = Dictionary(grouping: strings) { $0.prefix(2) }
    .filter { $0.value.count > 1 }
```

That returns:

> ["A1": ["A1A2", "A1B1"], "E3": ["E3D3", "E3E4"], "B1": ["B1A1", "B1C1”]]

Or, if you only want the duplicates as an array:

```
let duplicates = Dictionary(grouping: strings) { $0.prefix(2) }
    .filter { $0.value.count > 1 }
    .map { $0.value }
```

That returns:

> [["B1A1", "B1C1"], ["E3D3", "E3E4"], ["A1A2", "A1B1”]]

Or, if you just want a flat array:

```
let duplicates = Dictionary(grouping: strings) { $0.prefix(2) }
    .filter { $0.value.count > 1 }
    .flatMap { $0.value }
```

Returns

> ["B1A1", "B1C1", "A1A2", "A1B1", "E3D3", "E3E4”]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to consider the complexity, you can use `reduce(into:)` method:

```
let array = ["A2A1", "A1A2", "A1B1", "B1A1", "B1C1", "C1B1", "D3E3", "E4E3", "E3D3", "E3E4"]
let result = array.reduce(into: [String: [String]]()) { (dict, element) in
  let key = String(element.prefix(2))
  dict[key, default:[]].append(element)
}
```

**EDITED** Thanks for Rob's suggestion for the dictionary subscription with default parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much.   I will probably use this code as well for another problem.  LOL.

Comment: I appreciate the time spent.  This works as well... I just went with the bottom solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how long the given list is, but assume it can be large.

In that case, reducing with Dictionary will be efficient, in point of view of lookup.

```
let list = ["A2A1", "A1A2", "A1B1", "B1A1", "B1C1", "C1B1", "D3E3", "E4E3", "E3D3", "E3E4"]

var mapped = list.reduce(into: [String: [String]]()) { (dict, item) in
    let substr = String(item.prefix(2))
    dict[substr, default: []].append(item)
}

let res = Array(mapped.values).filter { $0.count > 1 }
debugPrint(res)
```

Comment: Again thank you.   Yes a dictionary is going to be very helpful for larger projects.  This one the data set is smaller.  Again I have bookmarked this page for future reference.

Comment: You can filter the values before promoting them to an array (to save on copying them). Also, this dictionary-building idiom has been obsolete since Swift 4, with the introduction of [`Dictionary.init(grouping:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995342-init)